# SDL2 possible linking issue in VS2017

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, sdl-2

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with OpenGLESApp template and I'm trying to put SDL2 into my project. I linked  it by clicking Android.NativeActivity properties and in there I selected include folder and in linking part I linked against pre-compiled x86 binary which I downloaded from official SDL2 webpage.

Now since I'm using emulator with x86 base image I'm assuming that those things are compatible. Is my assumption wrong?

When I try to use SDL2 functions in my code compiler is complaining with the following error message:

```
Error   MSB6006 "clang.exe" exited with code 1.
```

And when I delete all usages of SDL2 functions code compiles just fine. Now this would perhaps indicate that architectures are not compatible and that my initial assumption is wrong.

Can somebody help me to understand this? Is there any way I can see more information from the compiler to validate what the actual issue is?

Also, any help on how to get SDL2 to run in my project would be helpful.

Comment: ...are you making a win32 or Android project? Are you trying to mix the 2?

Comment: so currently I'm developing on Android Emulator using Google API's Intel x86 Atom System Image, so I'm assuming that the code which is being deployed to my emulator is x86

Comment: win32 packages are not compatible with android (just like Linux binaries are not compatible with Windows or Mac).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have undefined references in your output before the error you are showing.

You are trying to link windows libraries with Android binaries, which cannot work, they are not the proper type. Even if they both can be executed on a x86 machine, they have a different structure.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try it out before accepting your answer. :)

Comment: Of course. If you install the proper package (Android x86), should OK ;)